# I tried to open html in a new tab and tried //window.open("home.html", '_self'); but it did not work

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open new HTML page in the same tab. I tried using `window.open('home.html','_self');`, but this does not work. However, if I use `window.open('home.html');`, it opens in a new window.

How can I open HTML in the same page? I have tried all of these but none of them worked:

```
//window.open("home.html", '_top');
//window.location.replace("home.html");
//window.open('home.html','_self');
//window.location.assign("home.html")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `window.location.href` function.

E.g. `window.location.href = "home.html";`

Comment: function userChoice() {

    var x;
    x = document.getElementById('yesno').value;

    console.log(x);

    if (x == 'n' || x == 'N') {
        window.open('home.html', '_self');

    }
    else {
        loadQuestion(currentQuestion);

    }
}

Comment: window.location.href = "home.html"; also does not work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want to use this in HTML or JQuery...whatever:

HTML

```
<a href="home.html">Home</a>
```

Jquery

```
location.href = "home.html";
```

Comment: I want to redirect from javaScript putting some condition. but I have also tried location.href = "home.html";

Comment: Does not work. It works for window.open('home.html'); but opens in new tab. non of others are working. sad!

Comment: That's weird....I used a lot    window.open("home.html", "_self");    but apparently it does not work for you...still weird, I don't know what else to say, I'm sorry :/

Comment: Thank you any way. Its really weird.